# NpgSql failed to Establish a connection with PostgreSql

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, virtual-machine, console-application

I am using npgsql 2.2.7 with asp dot net console app and application can connect fine with azure postgres DB on my local PC. Getting connection **timeout errors** while running it from my **Azure VM**.Even I can connect also my azure postgres db using pgAdmin from my Azure VM.

```
 Npgsql.NpgsqlException:
Failed to extablish a connection to protgres.database.azure.com
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCloseState.Open(NpgsqlConnector context, Int32 timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
```

My connection string for postgres SQL:

```
<add name="DbConnectionString" connectionString="User Id=  ;Password= ; Server= ;Port=5432;Database=  ; SslMode=Require" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

Tried adding timeout parameter with postgres connection string but it didn't work still getting the same error.

Comment: You have allowed other pc's (other then localhost) to connect to that postgresql instance in the configuration?

Comment: Yes, permission is given to all other's pc's to connect azure Postgres. Already I tested it from my azure VM which works fine.

Comment: After Updating npgsql  Library with the latest stable 5.0.10 version and add the timeout parameter with postgres connection string now my timeout issue has gone in Azure VM.